# how to change the size of a div from google map

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to resize the div from google map, but I don't have the code in my html file, I used the map in this code, I don't have the code anymore

```
    <iframe class="map-content"
        src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q={{json_decode($project->location,true)['lat']}},{{json_decode($project->location,true)['long']}}&output=embed">
    </iframe>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like there are classes called place-card and place-card-large. You could try writing some CSS to override those, if they contain size instructions in their current definition (your browser's element inspector can tell you that)

Comment: @ADyson I tried to change the size using these classes but it didn't work

Comment: @ADyson ok I get it thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You cannot overwrite the styles of an `iframe` that is loaded elsewhere.